# How to convert CTE to normal query?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb, common-table-expression

How can I convert this to normal query?

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT agentID, 
           SUM(bonus > 0) OVER (PARTITION BY agentID 
                                ORDER BY `year` * 12 + `month`
                                RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) flag
    FROM test
)
SELECT agentID
FROM cte
WHERE flag = 3;
```

I need to convert this because I think mariadb is not compatible with cte. I am not really familiar with cte too and I don't have any idea how to break this down to normal sql query in php.

UPDATE:

I tried doing this to run the cte

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "sample_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT agentID, bonus FROM (WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT agentID, 
           SUM(bonus > 0) OVER (PARTITION BY agentID 
                                ORDER BY `year` * 12 + `month`
                                RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) flag
    FROM sample_tbl
)) where agentID = '10710' && flag = 3");

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
        echo "You are elligible to take a course!";
    } else{
           echo "You are not elligible to take a course!";
        }




?>
```

but it is not working, the result shows

> "Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your
> SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near ') where agentID = '10710' &&
> flag = 3' at line 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\try\index.php:16 Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\try\index.php(16): mysqli->query('SELECT agentID,...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\try\index.php on
> line 16"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Again:

It is now working for me, here is my final code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "sample_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT agentID FROM (SELECT DISTINCT agentID, 
SUM(bonus > 0) OVER (PARTITION BY agentID 
                     ORDER BY `year` * 12 + `month`
                     RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) flag from sample_tbl) as cte where agentID = '61599' && flag = 3");

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
        echo "You are elligible to take a course!";
    } else{
           echo "You are not elligible to take a course!";
        }




?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed [MariaDB is compatible with CTEs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/common-table-expressions/), however if you don't want to deal with ctes for whatever reason, you can always transform it into a subquery:

```
SELECT agentID
FROM (
    SELECT agentID, 
           SUM(bonus > 0) OVER (PARTITION BY agentID 
                                ORDER BY `year` * 12 + `month`
                                RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) flag
    FROM test ) agents_with_summed_bonus
WHERE flag = 3;
```

If this query, in place of the one built with cte, doesn't work for you, then it means that you're initial query has some mistakes in relation of your tables.

Comment: And such subquery in the FROM clause is called a _derived table_.

Comment: ignoring cte's is fine but, don't overlook them they can be a great way to aggregate information and if I am not missing something cte's are usually less expensive (performance wise) than subqueries